# Formal proof for an easy calculus result

Tags: calculus, inequality

I have the following situation: Suppose $x,y$ are real numbers with $y > 0$. Then, I would like to show that for small values of $t$, we have

$$ (tx)^2 + (ty - 1)^2 \leq 1 $$

How can I show this in a formal manner?? For instance, I find myself struggling because I don't know that is the definition of small values of $t$.

Can someone help me? thanks

Comment: small value of t means that for there exists an $\epsilon$ greater than 0 below which the inequality holds

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Expand the inequality. You'll find that as long as $t>0$, you'll arrive at
$$ t \leq \frac{2y}{x^2+y^2}. $$

Assuming $t>0$, the steps to get there are completely reversible, so formally speaking: given an $(x,y)$, you can always find a $t$ (any $t$ satisfying the above inequality) such that $(tx)^2+(ty-1)^2\leq1$.

Answer (score 1):

Geometrically (so is informal...), let $(x, y)$ be a vector in $\mathbb R^2$. As $y>0$, $(x, y)$ is pointing upward. The inequality

$$(tx)^2 + (ty-1)^2 \leq 1$$

is the same as saying that for small positive $t$, the vector $t(x, y)$ lies in the ball centered at $(0,1)$ with radius one. This is pretty obvious.